# regexp matching slug

Tags: python, regex

Please help with slug regexp. 
I would appreciate if the code will be given in python. 
Conditions:

```
1 #valid 
1-1 #valid
1-1-1 #valid (infinite \d-\d)

1- #invalid
-1 #invalid
-1- #invalid

*NOTE 1 = \d
```

Comment: You should show is what you've tried so we can critique, rather than just asking for a hand out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would write it this way:

```
compiled = re.compile(r'\d(?:-\d)*$')
result = compiled.match(string_to_parse)
```

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
re.match(r'\d(?:-\d)*$', s)
```

Comment: There is no need for `^` since you are using `match` (not `search`). And it's better no use non-capturing group `(?:-\d)` since it's faster than capturing and there is no need to capture anything.